# try run to `eof script batch file` (.bat)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, eof

I have scrip contain command line:

```
set dir=%1
cd %dir%

test.bat

echo successful
```

---

When run this script, file `test.bat` (this file run `phpunit`) run complete then this script don't run command line `echo successful`.

So, how to try run to `eof script`.

Comment: I see the problem in your code, but I honestly have no clue at all what you mean with »eof script batch file« here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `call test.bat`.

When you try running a batch file from another batch like in your question control does not pass back to your calling batch.

---

Side note: I'd usually use `pushd`/`popd` for going into directories from batch files. At least I prefer when a batch file doesn't have a side-effect on the shell I'm working on (similar rationale for `setlocal`). Also this solves the problem when you pass a directory on another drive (although you could do `cd /d` in that case.